# How do I get a data attribute of a selected option via vanialla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, select, dataset

I am trying to get a data attribute of a selected option using vanilla JavaScript.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

<select id="roomno" name="roomno">
    <option value="1" data-daily-rate="50" data-weekly-rate="300" data-monthly-rate="1200">1 - Single room</option>
    <option value="2" data-daily-rate="100" data-weekly-rate="600" data-monthly-rate="2500">2 - Double Bedroom</option>
    <option value="3" data-daily-rate="150" data-weekly-rate="850" data-monthly-rate="4000">3 - Deluxe</option>    
</select>

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () =>
{
    $("#roomno").on("change", function() // Used jQuery only for this
    {     
        calculateRate();
    });
});

function calculateRate()
{
    let roomno = document.getElementById("roomno");
    let daily_rate = roomno.dataset['daily-rate'];
    console.log(daily_rate);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To get selected option you can use:

   ```
   var roomno = e.options[e.selectedIndex];
   ```
2. To get the selected option's dataset value you can use

   ```
    roomno.dataset.dailyRate
    // Or,
    roomno.dataset['dailyRate']
   ```

   Also, you can access other data attributes like:

   ```
    roomno.dataset.dailyRate
    roomno.dataset.weeklyRate
    roomno.dataset.monthlyRate
   ```
3. Also, you do not need to use jQuery only for this: `$("#roomno").on("change", function()`. You can attach `change` event listner like:

   ```
    document.getElementById("roomno").addEventListener("change", calculateRate);
   ```

**DEMO HERE:**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.getElementById("roomno").addEventListener("change", calculateRate);
});

function calculateRate() {
  let e = document.getElementById("roomno");
  var roomno = e.options[e.selectedIndex];
  let daily_rate = roomno.dataset.dailyRate;
  console.log(daily_rate);
}
```

```html
<select id="roomno" name="roomno">
  <option value="0" >-- Select --</option>
  <option value="1" data-daily-rate="50" data-weekly-rate="300" data-monthly-rate="1200">1 - Single room</option>
  <option value="2" data-daily-rate="100" data-weekly-rate="600" data-monthly-rate="2500">2 - Double Bedroom</option>
  <option value="3" data-daily-rate="150" data-weekly-rate="850" data-monthly-rate="4000">3 - Deluxe</option>
</select>
```